Problemas con el VSC en windows
Mi vsc me estaba tirando errores en los include, busque un video para solucionarlo y dejo de hacerlo. Pero ahora me tira error cuando quiero ejecutar un simple condigo en C, el cual no tiene errores, porque es este:
int main(){
    printf("hola");
    return 0;
}



Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera medalla! que error?

Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.
